# Is it correct to say ''you ARE to be back here before dark''

Tags: word-choice, formality, modal-verbs

I'm reading a novel and a character says this line:''you ARE to be back here before dark''
but I could not find this usage of the verb to be in my dictionary, so here I ask you if this is informal English for saying ''you MUST or HAVE TO be back before dark''.

Comment: I would say that similar language could be used in some sort of specification document, so it's reasonably formal.  And it is an imperative statement.

Comment: Is the all-caps "ARE" in the original?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613772/2085).

Answer (score 4):

It's grammatical, and means what you say, but as regards register lies towards or at the other extreme, being formal to highly formal:

> **be to [do something]** FORMAL
>
> 1 used for telling someone what to do
>
> *You are to stay here until I send for you.*
>
> ... *All books are to be returned by Friday.*

[[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be)]

A confusable usage is

> 3 used for saying or asking what should be done
>
> *What are we to do?*
>
> *You are to be congratulated on your wise decision.*

Comment: In my dialect, it's a stern admonition, not necessarily a formality. *You're to be home by midnight, no ifs, ands, or buts!*

Comment: I've adjusted slightly, but still consider it always in the formal half of the continuum, usually near the extreme. I'm sure most parents would say 'I want you back by ...' / 'Be home by ...' / 'You must be home by ...' .... Perhaps it's less marked in Scotland.

Comment: Could be dialect difference. In my neck of the woods, "You must be home by midnight" is a command the teenager can meet with a non-committal blank look; whereas "You're to be home by midnight" is a demand which expects at least a nod of assent.